# Mysterious $message in Facebook notification emails

Tags: php, facebook, email

It might seem like a silly question but I'm wondering why on earth there is a hidden `$message` inside the notification emails that are sent by Facebook when a friend of yours has updated his/her status.

If you've never noticed it, inspect the source code of these emails and you'll find this:

```
<span style="color:#ffffff; display:none!important; font-size:1px">$message</span>
```

This piece of code is obviously harmless but it still pollutes the email preview before opening it. I guess it is a small glitch in the email generation process, probably inside a PHP function that contains a `$message` variable.

Does anyone know more about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a bug of some kind. Inspect the email headers and backtrace the IP, if the IP is registered on Facebook it's all good. Otherwise report it to FB :)

Comment: I double checked the IP as you suggested: I am now a 100% sure that these emails have been sent by Facebook. I should probably report this bug anyway. Thanks for your answer, I'll keep you updated! :)

Comment: Awesome that you figured it out :)

Comment: They seem to have corrected the bug! :) I reported it few weeks ago, then got a generic answer saying something like "We'll consider it".